# If $f$ is uniformly continuous at $(a,b)$ and continous at $x=a$ how to prove it is uniformly continuous at $[a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is uniformly continuous at $(a,b)$ and continous at $x=a$ how to prove it is uniformly continuous at $[a,b)$?

can someone give a hint plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so elegant option:

Let $a<c<b$;

1) $f$ is uniformly  cont. on $[a,c]$, closed, bounded interval.

2) $f$ is uniformly continuos on $[c,b)$, since $[c,b) \subset (a,b)$.

Given $\epsilon/2$.

1) There is a $\delta_1$ s.t. for $x,y \in [a,c]$

$|x-y|<\delta_1$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$.

2) There is a $\delta_2$ s.t. for $x,y \in [c,b)$

$|x-y|<\delta_2$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$.

$\delta =\min (\delta_1,\delta_2)$.

3) Let $x<c$ ,  $c<y$, and $|x-y|<\delta$.

Then

$(y-c)+(c-x) <\delta$ implies

$|f(y)-f(x)|\le $

$|f(y)-f(c)| +|f(x)-f(c)| <$

$\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$.

Comment: It seems nice, thank you for the help. If i understood well, you did (3) in order to show that also in the union of the ranges, you get a uniformly continuous functions.

Comment: Alon.Yes:) If $x,y$ in 1) or 2) take min of the respective deltas and you are fine. Small complication: 3) $x$ could be in 1) and $y$ in 2) , what then ?  $|y-x|<\delta$ , i.e. $(y-c)+(c-x)<\delta$, implies $y-c<\delta$, $c-x<\delta$, and you can use $|f(c)-f(x)|<\epsilon/2$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$ in 1) and 2).Ok?

Comment: I will think of it more, but it gives a good idea, i will work on it, thanks again. If i will have more questions, i will if its ok.

Comment: Alon.Of course it is ok. Try to retrace the steps. Each step, and reason.Look at Carlos answer too. And ask anytime. :)

Comment: Why do you take the min delta? How can you be sure that the min will satisfy what you want? Why not to take the max delta?

Comment: Assume in an interval [a,b] you have a uniformly cont. function. Means $\epsilon$ given there is a $\delta $say $\delta =1$ for the given $\epsilon$, s.t. $|x-y|<1$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon$. Question: Will $|x-y|<1/2$ guarantee $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$? Will $\delta=2$ guarantee it? $\delta=1/2$ is ok, since if $|x-y|<1/2$ then it is also <1, and you can use the original statement. $\delta =2$ ? Now you have 2 different deltas for 2 statements. If you pick the smaller =(min) then you can use it for both.ok?

Comment: Yes i think its ok now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Take $\delta_1>0$ such that$$(\forall x,y\in(a,b)):\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta_1\implies\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(y)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$$amd take $\delta_2>0$ such that$$(\forall x\in(a,b)):\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta_2\implies\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(a)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon.$$Now, take $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. That will work.

Comment: Thank you, but lets say $\delta_2$ is the min. maybe now $|x-y| > \delta_2$ so how it is uniformly continous?

Comment: That makes no sense. I claim that, with the delta that I defined,$$\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta\implies\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(y)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: I apologize, i dont see why what i say make no sense, maybe $\delta_2 < |x-y| $ and $\delta_2$ is the min, therefore, $|x-y| > \delta$...